# Intuitive understanding of bond dimensions

Tags: tensor-network

I am trying to understand what is bond dimension in tensor network more intuitively, by meaning of bond dimension I meant the tensor dimension that connects between tensors (in the example below the bond dimension will be the a's indices. .
I know that bond dimension related to the entanglement entropy with exponential relationship $D\approx\exp{S}$, but I can't understand is how to determine the bond dimension D.
Let us say we have a product state wave function:
$|\psi \rangle=\sum_{a_1,...,a_N}A^{i_1}_{a_1}A^{i_2}_{a_1,a_2}....A^{i_N}_{a_N}|i_1,...,i_N\rangle$.
Then how can I know how to determine the bond dimension? and if I will apply some H on it, the how can I tell what will be the bond dimension D on the next step ?

Comment: Please indicate the object or topic you talk about, using the EDIT button for your question. Thanks

Comment: Is the correction ok ?

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, „bond“ has many meanings. Do you talk about chemical bonds? Please clarify, als its relationship with wave functions.

Comment: I added the explanation. Hopes it is useful.

Comment: Bond dimensions are simply the dimensions of the tensors $A^{i_k}_{a_{k-1}a_k}$ corresponding to the indices $a_{k-1}, a_{k}$. What do you mean by determining bond dimensions? If the wavefunction is initially written in MPS form with known tensors $A^{i_k}_{a_{k-1}a_k}$, the bond dimensions are already known.